# Filter data-frame with regex, using a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have data-frame with the following columns: `Hello`, `World`, `Python`, `Hello_X`, `World_X`, `Python_X`.

Also, I have this list: `['Hello','World']`.

Using that list, I want to filter the data-frame and remain with these columns: `Hello`, `World`, `Hello_X`, `World_X`.

- **Note that I have thousands of columns in the real data-frame, so please don't provide a "manual" solution.**

Comment: Please show a piece of code, and what is X ? just 'X' letter or anything ? I supposed exact match with X is anything in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a regex string like `(Hello|World|...)` automatically from the list of words that you're searching for, then apply it with `filter`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[
    'Hello', 'World', 'Python', 'Hello_X', 'World_X', 'Python_X'])

cols = ['Hello', 'World']
df.filter(regex='(' + '|'.join(cols) + ')')
```

Comment: Careful though, this might break if your selected columns contain `|` in their names.

Comment: If that is the case, `|` must be escaped in `cols` with `\|`

Comment: this could break if you have columns with names starting with the same letters. Like "Hell", "Hello", and you don t want both. regexp can be improved.

Comment: @Malo If there is a column 'Hell', it will not be matched by 'Hello' regex. Maybe I'm missing your point?

Comment: We would, of course, match any column name **containing** the word in the list, not necessarily starting with it, but there is no indication in the question that what we're trying to achieve is finding columns **starting** with these words

Comment: @perl if you search for a column "Hell" the regex given here will also match "Hello" column. Please have a look at my proposed regex and answer to avoid this problem. It depends on what the OP really needs.

Comment: Sure, if you search for 'Hell' you'll match 'Hello' as well. Based on the question, I would think that's how it's intended to work

Comment: The OP should have given more details about this. Let s wait for what he will tell us.

Comment: Yes, exactly, without more clarity on what's intended, we can only assume

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution with an improved regex which will take column names, and names, plus underscore (required), plus something (not only 'X' letter). The regexp won't match names starting the same way, and will require underscore + anything after the required name.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame( np.array(([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17] )),
        columns=['Hello', 'World', 'Python', 'Hellow', 'Hello_X', 'World_X', 'Python_X'])

cols = ['Hello', 'World']

### building the regexp to match either column names or columns names with one '_' and something after

regex = ['(^'+x+'(_.*)+)' for x in cols] + ['(^'+x+'$)' for x in cols]
regex = r'|'.join(regex)

print(df.filter(regex=regex))
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this regex object

**Method-1**

```
df.filter(regex=r'(Hello(_X)?|World(_X)?)')
```

---

**Method-2**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Hello', 'World', 'Python', 'Hello_X', 'World_X', 'Python_X'])

regex=re.compile(r'(Hello(_X)?|World(_X)?)')

up_col = [i for i in df.columns if regex.search(i)]
df[up_col]
```

Output:

```
Columns: [Hello, World, Hello_X, World_X]
```

Comment: I allready mention that change the regex object in first line don't say that

Comment: I suppose 'X' should be anything ?and not just 'X' .. so better to use '.*?' in the regexp